# How to validate a checkcolumn using Ajax

Tags: extjs

A checkcolumn in a grid needs to be validated before the user changes its state:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'add',
    width: 70,
    text: 'Add',
    listeners: {
        beforecheckchange: 'onPermissionChangeCheckAllowed'
    }
}
```

At the moment `onPermissionChangeCheckAllowed` validates using *sync* Ajax, like:

```
onPermissionChangeCheckAllowed: function (chk, rowIndex, checked, record, e, eOpts) {
   var result = Ext.Ajax.request({
                  async: false,
                  url: '/checkUserPermission',
                  params: Ext.encode(record)
   });

   return result;
}
```

This works --but `async: false` freezes the browser (for a ms) and I would like to know: is there another option to make this validation? In fact the console shows the warning that this behaviour will be deprecated :-O

The grid is a pivot table (done with SQL, not with Ext Pivot), so it is necessary to send the exact checkbox co-ordinates since there is no valid id (i.e. submitting the record doesn't provide enough information about the column name and the id is an autogenerated Ext id).

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because javascript is single threaded by nature. You should be either passing a permissions flag to the browser to  create the logic to hide/disable the checkbox to the user AND validating on the server side.

If you really want to do an ajax call on each checkbox click (you absolutely shouldn't), you need to:

1. Block the change if it was clicked by the user
2. Send an ajax request
3. Set the checkbox pragmatically

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not freezing (yet), but agreed that it's not the best approach. The question is more related to the first step that you mention: block the change. I was using `beforecheckchange` event, but how to make it wait until the validation is done? Finally what I have done is forget about the `beforecheckchange` event and simply use the `checkchange` to validate it. Yes, it has to be done on every change the user clicks: it's a grid with user permissions, each one must be validated against ACL. If you have a method for your first step, please share it :-)

Comment: if you `return false` in the beforecheckchange it will not change the checkbox. At the successful Ajax.request you can set it with a custom flag to the checkbox.forceCheckChange